# lua corona - How to load an image using loadRemoteImage

Tags: image, lua, coronasdk, loading

I want to load an image from a URL.
I can load an image using this code:

```
local group = display.newGroup();  
local testImg;  
testImg = display.newImage( "cells/cellBottom.png");  
group:insert( testImg );
```

but i need to use something like:

```
testImg = display.loadRemoteImage( "https://www.dropbox.com/s/fqlwsa5gupt5rsj/amcCells.png")
group:insert( testImg );
```

Please tell me how to load this image.
Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use example given in Corona. This works with the following url but your url seems to have problem.

```
local function networkListener( event )
    if ( event.isError ) then
        print ( "Network error - download failed" )
    else
        event.target.alpha = 0
        transition.to( event.target, { alpha = 1.0 } )
    end

    print ( "event.response.fullPath: ", event.response.fullPath )
    print ( "event.response.filename: ", event.response.filename )
    print ( "event.response.baseDirectory: ", event.response.baseDirectory )
end

display.loadRemoteImage( "http://coronalabs.com/images/coronalogogrey.png", "GET", networkListener, "coronalogogrey.png", system.TemporaryDirectory, 50, 50 )
```

Comment: thanks @Amir :)
Your code works fine. Do you have any idea why my url doesn't work?
I've also tried 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wsaueltlqhqo168/GameEditor.jpg
many thanks

Comment: It is something to do with Dropbox and google drive etc services. They usually require you to use their API to access this way. FOr example try this from parse.com with the code above which still works fine http://files.parsetfss.com/d46d0479-76ab-4480-b805-18ebd85f2591/tfss-1bd5b18d-3510-417f-9088-f38a5bba3d30-Resize%20of%203.png

Answer (score 0):

try add yougroup:insert(event.target) in listener

```
local function networkListener( event )
if ( event.isError ) then
    print ( "Network error - download failed" )
else
    event.target.alpha = 0
    transition.to( event.target, { alpha = 1.0 } )
    **yourgroup:insert(event.target)**
end

print ( "event.response.fullPath: ", event.response.fullPath )
print ( "event.response.filename: ", event.response.filename )
print ( "event.response.baseDirectory: ", event.response.baseDirectory )
```

end

display.loadRemoteImage( "http://coronalabs.com/images/coronalogogrey.png", "GET", networkListener, "coronalogogrey.png", system.TemporaryDirectory, 50, 50 )